# Return an employee's first + lastname and their manager's first + last name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query in SQL to return an employee's first + lastname and their manager's first + last name from the same "employee" table. Each employee has an employeeid and a "reportsto" column which contains the employeeid of their manager.

This is what I have so far that returns the first part (an employee's first + lastname and the id of who the report to)

```
SELECT employee.employeeid, employee.firstname, employee.lastname, employee.reportsto
FROM employee
WHERE employee.reportsto IS NOT NULL;
```

This returns

```
 employeeid | firstname | lastname | reportsto
------------+-----------+----------+-----------
          2 | Nancy     | Edwards  |         1
          3 | Jane      | Peacock  |         2
          4 | Margaret  | Park     |         2
          5 | Steve     | Johnson  |         2
          6 | Michael   | Mitchell |         1
          7 | Robert    | King     |         6
          8 | Laura     | Callahan |         6
```

I'm not sure how to take that "reportsto", grab which employeeid it corresponds to, and then add the first + last name of the manager employee and add it to the same record.

So the table should go "employeeid, firstname, lastname, managerFirstName, managerLastName"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do a _self join_, i.e. `employee e join employee m`. Perhaps LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a *self join* to get the manager names.

```
SELECT e.employeeid, e.firstname, e.lastname,
       m.firstname managerFirstName, m.lastname managerLastName
FROM employee e
JOIN employee m ON e.reportsto = m.employeeid 
WHERE e.reportsto IS NOT NULL;
```